# Un-editable form fields for anonymous users

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to create form fields un-editable for anonymous users, that can be editable for other registered users. How can I do? I am using the webform module with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a custom module](https://drupal.org/node/1074360) and use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to achieve that.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == "YOUR_FORM_ID")
    {
        $form['name']['#disabled'] = TRUE; // or something similar.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but now I'm using a lock_field_module for webform_module in drupal 7.